# Why does the quality of the image increase as the resolution increases?

Tags: image

I have got an `img` element in my HTML document, and its width is about 100px.

The outputs when I set the source to images of different widths that I change every time:

**17000 px:**

[image: Logo of 17000 px width]

**2000 px:**

[image: Logo of 2000 px width]

**500 px:**

[image: Logo of 500 px width]

**100 px:**

[image: Logo of 100 px width]

As you can see, the quality of the image reduces even though the `img` element's width is at a constant 100px. Is there any reason behind this? If so, what are the practises to be followed to ensure the quality isn't bad?

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking these as screenshots? I'm thinking that the image looks less clear because you have a low resolution when you display them. As in, the area you are showing the image in on your monitor is of a lower resolution than the image itself. So, by making the area displayed larger your monitor can more accurately display the image.

Think of it like this: Displaying a 4K wallpaper on a 720p display won't look as good because the monitor has to scale it down.

Slightly related reading to browser image resizing: https://petapixel.com/2009/11/12/why-you-should-never-let-browsers-resize-your-photos/

Comment: I would agree to that in usual circumstances, but this is a case where the very tag that holds the image is only 100 pixels wide. So essentially, drawing a 17,000 pixel wide image in a 100 pixel container by scaling it down should make the image look worse, not better. However, in my case, it looks better than in the case of 2000, 500 and 100 px wide images.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the code in question? It may be browser dependent